# resignFirstResponder and endEditing (even global calls) are not hiding the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a `ViewController` set as a delegate for a `UITextField`. No matter what I try, I can not get the keyboard to hide when calling `textFieldShouldReturn`.

My `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(newModelField)
    newModelField.delegate = self
    self.presetTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "presetCell")
    //self.view.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

and my `textFieldShouldReturn` method:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    //UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction("resignFirstResponder", to:nil, from:nil, forEvent:nil)
    if(textField.text! != ""){
        items.append(textField.text!)
        presetTableView.reloadData()
        textField.text! = ""
        //self.view.resignFirstResponder()
        //self.addView.resignFirstResponder()
        //textField.endEditing(true)
        //self.view.endEditing(true)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window?!.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

You can see from my commented out attempts that I have tried a whole host of different fixes. I know that `textFieldShouldReturn` is being called after debugging with print statements. I can not figure out why the keyboard won't hide.

I tried swapping the return true and false statements. I tried setting the delegate from the storyboard. I tried deleting the textField from storyboard, cleaning, and adding it back in. I tried all top level calls to `resignFirstResponder` and `endEditing` as well as calls to these functions for the textfield and the view.

Comment: I solved it by calling self.view.endEditing(true) in both functions textFieldShouldEndEditing and textFieldShouldReturn. Not sure why but that's the only way it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

> To dismiss the keyboard, send the resignFirstResponder message to the text >field that is currently the first responder. Doing so causes the text >field object to end the current editing session (with the delegate >object’s consent) and hide the keyboard.

```
yourTextField.resignFirstResponder()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using resignFirstResponder() on textFiled and also used endEditing(true) on my view but I did this small mistake of implementing this other delegate and was returning false

```
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {  //delegate method
    return true
}
```